# Hybrid mobile app for video chat and recording

Tags: twilio, compatibility, hybrid-mobile-app, flutter, videochat

I want to build a mobile application which is social networking and allows users to have video chats. The video chats should also be able to get recorded and shared. So I am opting for Hybrid app development as I can release the app both in iOS and android. 
For my requirements what Hybrid platform should I opt?
I came across Twilio services which provide video chat functionality, but is Twilio compatible with Hybrid apps?
If yes, I am more inclined towards flutter(google's hybrid application framework), is flutter Twilio compatible?
If not, which other hybrid framework is Twilio compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As Flutter is newly in beta, I don't think many people have attempted a Twilio integration. The Flutter [video player plugin](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/video_player) is not complete yet either. Flutter might not be the best platform for this.

I believe that Twilio Video can be supported in other frameworks like Xamarin, React Native and Cordova. I've not personally used any of them, so that's as much as I can tell you.

Comment: Among Xamarin, React and Cordova, which is better to use Twilio for my requirements?

Comment: We don't have any officially supported plugins to any of those platforms and I haven't used them recently, so I don't know I'm afraid. I'd probably go with whichever platform you are most comfortable with.

Comment: Flutter is no longer in beta and should seriously be considered, as it compiles to native byte code and Twilio already has an Android and iOS SDK the technical lift here should not be immense.

Comment: You're right, but I don't have anything to report on whether we are building a supported plugin for Flutter yet. We hope to see if the community comes up with something too.

Comment: Still in development fase but we are working on a Flutter plugin: https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter-unofficial/programmable-video

Comment: @MarkVeenstra That's really cool, thanks for building this. Let me know if there's anything I can do to help (from a non-Flutter, non-mobile app developer point of view :D)

Comment: @philnash We are getting close to the first publish for Android. In next few days we will publish first version and than focus on iOS. If you want you may take a look at the Kotlin code and report or let us know anything we can do to improve it where necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Still in development fase at the moment but we are working on a Flutter plugin for Twilio Programmable Video. It can be found here: https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter/programmable-video

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend to try [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com)

They have hybrid Cordova/PhoneGap SDK and code samples for video chat:

Cordova Video Chat code sample - https://developers.connectycube.com/js/code-samples-videochat-cordova

Javascript/Cordova SDK - https://developers.connectycube.com/js/

Main features, in general:

- 1-1 video chat
- Group video chat
- Cross-platform
- WebRTC based
- Screen sharing
- VP8/H264 video codecs supported
- Mute/Unmute audio/video stream
- Switch video input devices (cameras)
- Video recording